# Empty response when trying retrieve a user's followers

Tags: api, instagram-api

Request (with my actual access token in place of `UserAccessToken`):

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/follows?access_token=UserAccessToken
```

Response:

```
{
  "pagination": {},
  "data": [],
  "meta": { "code": 200 }
}
```

Sandbox: YES

Invite to user: accepted

Has anyone had this problem? Please help!

Answer (score 0):

beacuse **your app in in sanbox mode** .

it **just show users insert in sanbox mode**.(just 3 people can inserted to this mode.)

follow this link to see more deatails :

https://www.instagram.com/developer/sandbox/

if it will be in live mode it will work(need to accept instagram company.).